# How can I get the number of skspritenodes in a scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want to find out what the number of nodes is in a scene.  For example, I want to create an `if` statement so that if the number of nodes in the scene is 0 or any other number, I would call a function.

This is what i have done but it only calls the function the first time children.count is 0 but ignores the other times.

I am not removing or adding any sprite nodes anywhere else in my code.

```
func dot(){
    var dotTexture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "dot")
    dotTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    var dot = SKSpriteNode(texture: dotTexture)
    dot.setScale(0.5)
    dot.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.5 , y: self.frame.size.height * 1.1)

    dot.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (circleOfRadius: dot.size.height/2.0)
    dot.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    dot.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    self.addChild(dot)


    println("done")

}

 override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if children.count == 0 {
        dot()

        println("dot")
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're removing sprites at some point, show us the code of how you're doing that, otherwise we can't tell you why you're experiencing this

Comment: that is my function and i am not adding or deleting sprite nodes any where else

Comment: If you're not removing sprites it will never be 0 again, as soon as you run the function dot, the children count becomes 1

Comment: **PLEASE** don't answer your question to the point of invalidating posted answers.  If your question wasn't clear enough for the posted answers to hold your hand all the way to your solution, mark one as accepted and post a new question.  The posted answers answered your question perfectly last time I looked at this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're doing this inside the scene itself you can do

```
if (self.children.count == x) {
   yourFunction() //call your function
}
```

or

```
if (children.count == x) {
    yourFunction() //call your function
}
```

in response to your comment:

there's an update method that runs every frame in sprite kit. Use it like this:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if (children.count == x) {
        yourFunction() //call your function
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but it only preforms the function once, even though the number of nodes becomes x more than once

Comment: Braces are not optional in Swift.  The parenthesis which you insisted on including, however, are optional.

Comment: but then it is giving me the error "unresolved identifier" for the function when i call it

Comment: @MostafaMohsen call your function, not the one I have. `function1()` is just an example

Comment: okay, it works but it seems for me putting it in the update method only calls the function the first time that x is 0, and then it doesn't call it the next time x is 0

Comment: how are you removing the sprites? are you calling `removeFromParent()` or just hiding them? if you just hide it, it might still be part of the "children" array

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
if (self.children.count == someNumber) {
    <#enter code here#>
}
```

where some number is a trigger number or expression.

Objective-C, use:

```
if ([self children].count == someNumber) {
    // enter code here
}
```

Also, where it says "enter code here," call your function and do what you need to do.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad He provided both options.  And honestly, given that there's no code in the question itself, I don't think it's really fair to call this a "Swift" question.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad And this answer has the Swift version, does it not?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find out what the number of nodes is in a scene

Use this method:

```
func nodeCount(scene:SKScene) -> Int {
    return scene[".//*"].count
}
```

This will give you the count of all nodes in the entire scene heirarchy.